# Blank screen on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Comrades help please.

I created ViewPager, and it displays a blank screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_textgrid);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.textpager);

    items = new ArrayList<RssItem>();


    LoadText loader = new LoadText();
    loader.execute();

}
```

---

```
private class LoadText extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<RssItem>> {

            @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<RssItem> result) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "LOADED:" + result.size());
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CUUR_ITEM:" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());

            pd.dismiss();
            items.addAll(result);
            adapter = new TextAdapter(TextActivity.this, items);

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (items.size() > 0) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "CUR_ITEM:" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
}
```

---

```
public class TextAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<RssItem> items;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public TextAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<RssItem> items) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this.items = items;

    }

    private RssItem getItem(int pos) {
        return this.items.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_text, container,
                false);

        RssItem item = getItem(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        TextView rating = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textRating);
        TextView author = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textAuthor);
        TextView content = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.textContent);

        content.setText(item.getContent());
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        rating.setText(item.getRating());
        author.setText(item.getAuthor());
        content.setText(item.getContent());

        return viewLayout;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

}
```

The logs appear that a lot of data uploaded.

if you change the program page, it changes (in the logs can be seen).

A blank screen = (

Comment: try debugging it and see if your code reached instantiateItem function for the 2nd item

Comment: @vipulmittal My code reached instantiateItem function for all items

Comment: I forgot to write the this code
'((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);'

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try use:

> viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = adapter.count